# Trying to understand why a dependency's JAR file is not added to classpath

Tags: libgdx, sbt

I'm trying to set up a Scala project which builds on the [libGDX](https://libgdx.com) game engine using sbt. After adding the necessary dependencies and trying to instantiate `LwjglApplication`, it fails to load the shared library `libgdx64.dylib`, which contains some native code for my platform (macOS 10.13.6).

These are the dependencies I've declared:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx" % "1.9.14"
libraryDependencies += "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-backend-lwjgl" % "1.9.14"
libraryDependencies += "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-platform" % "1.9.14" % "natives-desktop"
```

This is the exception I get:

```
sbt:test_libgdx> run
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/michi/Documents/Projects/Slick2D/test_libgdx/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[info] running Main 
[error] (run-main-3) com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx64.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 64-bit
[error] com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'libgdx64.dylib' for target: Mac OS X, 64-bit
[error]     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:120)
[...]
```

With my limited knowledge of sbt, ivy and Maven artifacts I've investigated a bit and noticed that the JAR file containing `libgdx64.dylib` (`gdx-platform-1.9.14-natives-desktop.jar`) is not added to the classpath of the running application. I've narrowed it down to a minimal project setup which shows this problem:

```
$ ls
build.sbt  project  target
$ cat build.sbt 
libraryDependencies += "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-platform" % "1.9.14" % "natives-desktop"
$ sbt
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.9 (AdoptOpenJDK Java 1.8.0_282)
[info] loading global plugins from [...]/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from [...]/test/project
[info] loading settings for project test from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to test (in build file:[...]/test/)
[info] sbt server started at local://[...]/.sbt/1.0/server/dd1267d773c22c32c889/sock
[info] started sbt server
sbt:test> show compile:dependencyClasspath
[info] * Attributed([...]/.sbt/boot/scala-2.12.12/lib/scala-library.jar)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 31, 2021 10:47:54 AM
sbt:test>
```

If I look in the maven repository at [`https://repo.maven.apache.org/...`](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/badlogicgames/gdx/gdx-platform/1.9.14/) manually, I can see that JAR file.

What do I need to do to get that JAR file on the classpath so that the shared library can be loaded from it? Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue - for sbt to comprehend an artifact with multiple builds (in this case, native binaries), instead of `%` you have to use a `classifier`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.badlogicgames.gdx" % "gdx-platform" %  "1.11.0" classifier "natives-desktop"
```